# Android 2.3 gingerbread is not renderring a barchart using achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

When I test a bar graph on my phone it displays nothing and this warning message appears
****on my emulator which is v4 it works perfectly.****

```
04-26 20:45:26.638: W/KeyCharacterMap(11541): Can't open keycharmap file
04-26 20:45:26.638: W/KeyCharacterMap(11541): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/melfas_touchkey.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='melfas_touchkey'
04-26 20:45:26.638: W/KeyCharacterMap(11541): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

is there any relation? and if not why the graph is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

My bad it was a small bug in my code, it works perfectly now
Regards